How to add dropdown to excel by javascript?
I want to automatic my excel-work-flow and I created some javascript to do my daily task. I need to implement dropdown with 3 options, and default none option.
I created this code, It correct add something on first column, but there is no dropdown, just empty space.
const addColumnWithMenu = (worksheet) => {
  const range = XLSXStyle.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
  const lastRow = range.e.r + 1;

  // Przesuń istniejące kolumny w prawo
  for (let C = range.e.c; C >= 0; --C) {
    for (let R = 0; R < lastRow; ++R) {
      const oldCellAddress = XLSXStyle.utils.encode_cell({ c: C, r: R });
      const newCellAddress = XLSXStyle.utils.encode_cell({ c: C + 1, r: R });
      worksheet[newCellAddress] = worksheet[oldCellAddress];
      if (C === 0) delete worksheet[oldCellAddress]; // Usuń starą komórkę, jeśli to pierwsza kolumna
    }
  }

  const menuValues = ['Paka', 'Magazyn', 'Szukam'];
  const colors = {
    Paka: 'FF00FF00', // zielony
    Magazyn: 'FFFFFF00', // pomarańczowy
    Szukam: 'FFFF0000', // czerwony
  };

  // Wypełnij nową kolumnę A wartościami z menu
  for (let R = 0; R < lastRow; ++R) {
    const cellAddress = `A${R + 1}`; // `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, ..., `An`

    // Ustawienie walidacji danych typu lista (dropdown)
    worksheet[cellAddress] = worksheet[cellAddress] || {};
    worksheet[cellAddress].v = ''; // Inicjalizuj wartość komórki jako pustą
    worksheet[cellAddress].s = worksheet[cellAddress].s || {
      fill: {
        patternType: 'solid',
        fgColor: { rgb: 'FFFFFFFF' }, // Domyślny kolor tła
      },
    };
    worksheet[cellAddress].dataValidation = {
      type: 'list',
      allowBlank: true,
      formulae: ['Paka', 'Magazyn', 'Szukam'],
    };
  }

  // Aktualizacja zakresu kolumn
  range.e.c += 1;
  worksheet['!ref'] = XLSXStyle.utils.encode_range(range);

  // Dodaj zdarzenie zmiany wartości komórki, aby zmieniać kolor tła w zależności od wartości
  for (let R = 0; R < lastRow; ++R) {
    const cellAddress = `A${R + 1}`;
    worksheet[cellAddress].s = worksheet[cellAddress].s || {};
    worksheet[cellAddress].s.fill = worksheet[cellAddress].s.fill || {};

    if (worksheet[cellAddress].v) {
      worksheet[cellAddress].s.fill.fgColor.rgb =
        colors[worksheet[cellAddress].v] || 'FFFFFFFF';
    }
  }
};


What happens if you replace your formulae property with formulae: ['"Paka,Magazyn,Szukam"'] or formulae: [ "Paka,Magazyn,Szukam" ] ?

no difference between this solutions. Ai tells to change library from  xlsx-style to  xlsx or another one and then try, but I am not sure if Microsoft Excel just support dropdown, in opposition to google sheet, because I have no this tool in my version of this program
